# How to create multi item template with wizard

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I'd like to be able to add many files (C#, XAML) at a time with parameters that I can fill in a form like Visual Studio's wizard.

The usage would be like:

Right-click on a project containing following structure:

- Controllers
- DAOS
- Views

Choose add -> new item and select "MyCompanyTemplate"

Then a form would ask for say classname, time and appleType.

Once this form filled with classname=AAA, time=12:00 and appleType=Gravenstein, the result would be :

Controllers/AAAController.cs

```cs
namespace Controllers
{
    public class AAAController
    {
        private const string appleType = "Gravenstein";

        public AAAController() { }

        //// Whatever I need in this class
    }
}
```

Daos/AAADao.cs

```cs
namespace Daos
{
    public class AAADao
    {

        public AAADao() { }

        public void Count()
        {
            var whatsthetime = "12:00";
            string s = "Not very inspired for this example";
        }
        //// Whatever I need in this class

    }
}
```

- Views/AAAView.xaml
- Views/AAAView.xaml.cs

This is the kind of behavior we have when adding a new controller in ASP.Net MVC and choose to create the corresponding view, but with custom parameters added.

It must work with Visual Studio 2015 and/or 2017. I also have Resharper installed so any provided solution using this tool is welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to create a visual studio extension.

I use classes provided in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package namespace to add files to my projects and basic txt files with string replacement as templates.